# open twitter bootstrap modal window (Custom HTML Forms ) from iframe into the parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have a parent page with an iframe, and inside this iframe is some html/aspx forms that should open a modal window in the parent window,when called from parent page.The thing is, I dont have access to put code into the parent window. I just have access to this iframe. Is there a way this could be done with jquery and bootstrap with such limitations?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the parent window from the iframe by using window.parent. See [Window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent)

You could attach a modal window to the parent by appending it to the body of the parent document.

Comment: Yes, I have written custom renderModal function  into the parent which will show me the modal window to the parent by appending to the body of the parent window. 

The problem is that my form has some textbox and buttons and I need a different event callback to my iframe which runs some javascript/jquery. I can not put those jquery into the parent page that is my limitation here